# Как отправить сообщение в телеграме, имея только токен апи от аккаунта ( не от бота)

Tags: telegram, token

Хочу отправить сообщение имея токен от аккаунта в телеграмме. Нашел как отправить смс через бота и то чтобы отправить смс нужно чтоб человек подписался на этого бота и потом тогда можно отправить смс, говорят что это невозможно, но я уверен что это можно сделать, потому что на прошлой работе мы отправляли сообщение по телеграмму имея токен от аккаунта.